# Google Analytics Custom Segments in Custom Reports

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to pull a custom report in Google Analytics with custom-made segments as a dimension of the report. I don't see custom segments available in the list of dimensions. I can slice the pre-built GA views by custom segment as I want, but can't seem to add them to add them to a custom report or the api. Custom dimensions appear to be available as dimensions in custom reporting, but I do not have the ability to add new dimensions to the GA tag on the site.

Does anyone know if custom segments are available to pull into as dimensions of a custom report in Google Analytics or 360?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Segments are segments, they are a subset of your GA data. You should be able to add them to a custom report without issues though. Once applied, you should then see the data in the first column of the custom report for the particular dimension, split out into extra rows for applied segments.

[image]

Custom dimensions do require editing the tracking code or GA Tag within GTM to pass the custom dimension with the relevant hit(s)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I can't seem to figure out how to get the segments to show in a custom report. I only see options for dimensions and metrics, but not segments.

Comment: The same way you usually apply them to one of the GA standard reports in a View. Open the report and the default segment applied to it should be All Users. Click the box to the right of it that says +Add Segment and apply another segment.

Answer (score 1):

I have created two screen shots to supplement your previous reply.

This shows you how to select the custom segment:

[image: Google Analytics Custom Segment]

Once you have the custom segment added you will see the original segment in comparison to your newly added custom segment.

You can remove the original segment if you would like to isolate the custom segment by selecting the dropdown on the original segment and selecting "remove".

[image: Google Analytics Remove Segment]